# Susy Next Grids

Tags: sass, grid-layout, susy-compass

I'm just trying to familiarise myself with the new Susy Next options and I have my code:

```
.grid
   +clearfix
   clear: both

.grid__item
   +gallery(1)
   +rem(margin-bottom, 20px)
```

I want a 5 column grid inside `.grid` so that `.grid__item`'s span 1 column in a gallery formation.

If I add `+with-layout(5 1/4 fluid show background)` inside `.grid` then I don't get the debug background output.

If I  add `+container(5 1/4 fluid show background)` inside `.grid` then I get the background but the items don't span correctly as the context is not there.

Are there any docs on how to use `+with-layout` as I think that might solve it but can;t find anything on http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/install

I'm just after the best way to use Susy Next to solve this. I need `.grid` to contain 5 fluid columns with 1/4 gutters and to then allow me to span my `.grid__item`'s based upon it. I also need to be able to output debug backgrounds on `.grid`.

I think my main issue is that I am getting confused between: `+container`, `with-layout` and how things roll in together. I have read the latest docs but it doesn;t quite click in my head.

Might just be me!

Comment: sorry for this useless comment, but is `CSS` tag necessary for this question?

Comment: It outputs CSS does it not?

Comment: Yes, but that's the output. This issue is more related to SASS and Susy than CSS

Comment: @HashemQolami Just remove irrelevant tags.  If the Sass code doesn't generate the expected CSS, then it is a Sass problem.  If Sass is generating the expected CSS, but the CSS doesn't work as it should, then it is a CSS problem.

Comment: Can my question get answered now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to establish your grid. `with-layout` is one way to do that *for a small block of nested code*, but why not just set them globally? There are several ways you could do it, all of them [documented](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/settings/), but most likely you just want the `layout()` mixin:

```
// note that it isn't nested under anything.
+layout(5 1/4 fluid show background)
```

Now you have a global context, and you can build your grid:

```
.grid
  +container

.grid__item
  +gallery(1)
```

That's it. If you really just want the grid set for a small section of code, you can use `with-layout`. It works just like `layout`, but it only affects the code nested inside it.

```
// with-layout() for a nested code block:
+with-layout(5 1/4 fluid show background)
  .grid
    +container

  .grid__item
    +gallery(1)
```

Comment: Ok. Makes sense. I have my main global $susy grid set to 12 columns and that is set in my base/_variables.scss file. Then in a file called modules/_photo-display.scss file I am setting `.photo-display` to `+span(8)`. When I view my page, `.photo-display` has a width set of 100%. Do the global defaults set in my variables file not affect other individual files unless `+layout` is called at the top of it too? I think the separate files are confusing my grids.

Comment: Ah, I see what it's doing now. It's spanning 100% as the global context was set to 8 when I used `+layout(8 fluid)` in my previous file which is imported before the new `_photo-display.scss` file. I tried adding `+layout($susy)` to the top of my `_photo-display.scss` file to reset to the global grid but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I realise I could use +layout(12 fluid) at the top of `_photo-display.scss` and it will work but it seems silly having to redefine the grid when it could fallback to the original grid I set up as `$susy` ?

Comment: Any time you change the global settings, you are changing the value of `$susy`, and changing the layout for any code that follows. `layout($susy)` does nothing, because any layout you set is assigned to `$susy`. If you really want different layouts per file, you can either declare the `layout()` at the top, or use `with-layout` to wrap the code in each file, so your global settings remain.